# How to avoid flickering/blinking while showing or dismissing alertDialog from bottomSheetDialogFragment

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-bottomsheetdialog

While showing/dismissing alert dialog from my BottomSheetDialogFragment there is a blink on screen, How to avoid this? Thanks in advance.

```
AlertDialog alertDialog = AlertDialog.Builder(activity)
.setMessage(messageStringId)
.setPositiveButton(positiveButtonTextId) { _, _, _ ->
//Action
}
.setNegativeButton(negativeButtonTextId) { _, _, _ ->
//Action
}
.create()

alertDialog.show()
```

Issue: https://youtu.be/yR8XXgHchmA

Comment: If you show some gif or video with your question, It would be helpful to understand.

Comment: @brijeshkumar Thanks for the suggestion, updated with video link

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is something wrong in the way you added bottom sheet. I'm using BottomSheetDialogFragment and I don't see any blink as yours. Here is my code

```
class ItemListDialogFragment : BottomSheetDialogFragment() {
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_item_list_dialog, container, false)
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    show_dialog.setOnClickListener {
        AlertDialog.Builder(context!!)
            .setMessage("message")
            .setPositiveButton("ok", null)
            .setNegativeButton("cancel", null)
            .show()
    }
}
}
```